# SQL query of Count with multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have this query to count the times documentador is repeated in each table

```
(select count(documentador) AS count, documentador from impo_expo GROUP BY documentador order by documentador) UNION ALL
(select count(documentador), documentador from prov_compr GROUP BY documentador order by documentador) UNION ALL
(select count(documentador), documentador from pedimento GROUP BY documentador order by documentador) UNION ALL
(select count(documentador), documentador from partidas GROUP BY documentador order by documentador) order by documentador asc
```

OUTPUT:

```
count   documentador
2          Imelda
4          Imelda
2          Imelda
1          Imelda
2          Juan Enrique
1          Juan Enrique
1          Juan Enrique
1          Juan Enrique
2          Raul
```

How can i combine them to have something like this?

```
count   documentador
9         Imelda
5       Juan Enrique
2          Raul
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a "group by" and a "sum" around your query? Something like this:

```
select documentador, sum(count) as thesum from (
(select count(documentador) AS count, documentador from impo_expo GROUP BY documentador) UNION ALL
(select count(documentador), documentador from prov_compr GROUP BY documentador) UNION ALL
(select count(documentador), documentador from pedimento GROUP BY documentador) UNION ALL
(select count(documentador), documentador from partidas GROUP BY documentador) order by documentador asc
) a group by documentador order by thesum desc
```